# ActiveWndTrackTimeout Value Being Ignored

Tags: windows-8

I normally have Active Window Tracking (XMouse) turned on in my Windows 8 machine.  I wrote a small .Net utility to turn it on/off and adjust the delay.  Works great!

**After installing Windows 8.1, however, the ActiveWndTrackTimeout delay is being ignored no matter what value is in there.**  The window switch is occurring **immediately** regardless of the value in the registry:

[image: ActiveWndTrackTimeout entry in my Registry]

Has anyone else experienced this bug or have a fix for me?  I can easily turn the feature on/off, but I'd rather leave it on with a reasonable delay.

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro on a 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 12):

I had Win8 and "ActiveWndTrackTimeout" was working fine, but when I updated to Win8.1 it stopped working. I had to RENAME "ActiveWndTrackTimeout" to "ActiveWndTrkTimeout", sign out and in, and now it works in Win8.1 too.

Comment: I had same problem with Windows 7 and this solution of renaming + restarting worked for me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Maybe try `ActiveWndTrkTimeout`. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957203.aspx

Comment: I've added in an `ActiveWndtrkTimeout` entry but it makes no difference, the windows switch immediately and ignore the value in the registry.  I also tried removing the old `ActiveWndTrackTimeout` but still no change either.

Comment: My registry started with a value called "ActiveWndTrackTimeout" which had no effect.  When I renamed it to "ActiveWndTrkTimeout" it worked for me (Windows 7).

Answer (score 7):

Such an old question but still appears to be valid even for windows 10 (Seriously Microsoft you should fix it once and for all)

I started window 10 with **Windows 10 1703** (15063.1387 - I don't think these minors are important).

I had configured:
At path: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\`
value: `ActiveWndTrackTimeout` to `2000` (ms)

After upgrade to **Windows 10 1709** (16299.461) everthing stopped working again.
I haved added a registry DWORD key `ActiveWndtrkTimeout` with the same value (leaving the old key there) and the raise delay started to work again.

From the MSDN:

> ActiveWndTrkTimeout
>
> HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop
>
> REG_DWORD
> Milliseconds
> 0

0 is the default value.

### Note: I want to get one disinformation corrected

There is also a registry entry `MouseHoverTime` at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`.  This entry does not change the window raise delay.  It changes how fast are the taskbar information & preview shown.

### An update 17/12/2020

Here we go again, sigh Microsoft you should really improve your testing!

After **Windows 1909** (OS Build 18363.1139) update the hovering delay stopped working again!  I have added the deleted `ActiveWndTrkTimeout` again, but nothing happened to my surprise. (even after rebooting)

What you have to do *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Make the mouse easier to use* and uncheck the checkbox *Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse* click on *apply* button.  Then check the checkbox again and click on *apply* button again.  Now it works again!

Comment: wish I could upvote to get this answer to the top.  Your diligence is a benefit to us all!